# How to select word with parentheses via VBA MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

While insertion point on any word can be selected whole word but without "()". How can select with "()"

Example text : (3)

Selection.Expand unit:=wdWord

str = Selection

MsgBox str ' shows only "3"    not "(3)"

I just add the below code to solve;

```
Dim str As String
 With Selection.Find
   .ClearFormatting
   .Text = "("
   .Forward = False
   .MatchWildcards = False
   .Wrap = wdFindStop
   .Execute
 End With
   Selection.Extend
 With Selection.Find
  .Text = ")"
  .Forward = True
  .Execute
  .Text = ""
End With
 str = Selection
```

Comment: If the text example is inside a paragraph, it should be displayed as it is. Isn't it a list bullet?

Comment: Yes, it is inside a paragraph but it is selected without "( )" ?

Comment: Well, this is the way Word interprets the word meaning. Parenthesis only keep words between them... If you need it to consider the parenthesis as the same word you should select them, too. Otherwise, you have to play with `Selection.MoveStart` / `Selection.MoveEnd` to include them...